# How to improve performance scraping 20.000 url in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-scraping, threadpool

I have working a process that scrapes 20,000 urls, but it currently takes around 20 minutes to complete. I am looking for a way to improve this processing time.

> I have experimented with using `Thread.Start()` but have settled on `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

`StartScraping()` contains a loop to iterate through many Skus, which will resolve a URL for a product page that we want to check the stock status. We are concerned only if the stock is still available.

`GetUrlHtmlText()` is the method that does the actual HTML scrape using `HttpWebRequest`.  We determine if the product is available by checking for the presence of a button wuth the content `"Tükendi"`, this will indicate that the stock has been depleted (Sold Out).

#### Main Loop

```
public void StartScraping()
    {
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting => " + BrandName);
            foreach (var item in competitionItemList.competitionItems)
            {
                //Thread thread = new Thread(() => StartPerSku(BrandID, item, validProxyList[rnd.Next(0, validProxyList.Count - 1)], StockCheckStatus));
                //thread.Start();
                
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => StartPerSku(BrandID, item, validProxyList[rnd.Next(0, validProxyList.Count - 1)], StockCheckStatus));
                request++;
                Debug.WriteLine(request);
                counter++;
                if (counter == 10)
                {
                    validProxy = false;
                    proxyIndex++;
                    counter = 0;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    if (validProxyList.Count - 1 <= proxyIndex)
                    {
                        proxyIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
                // tasks.Add(thread); 
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            db.InsertRekabetWinServError(90002, "StartScraping() ==> " + ex.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("LetStartAllTask => " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

#### Scape logic

```
private async Task<bool> GetUrlHtmlText()
    {
        if (errorStatus)
        {
            htmlInnerText = "";
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, ch, sec) => { return true; };
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;

                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
                //byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);

                httpRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                httpRequest.Timeout = 30000;
                httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                httpRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36";
                httpRequest.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
                httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
                if (proxy != "0")
                {
                    httpRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
                }
                try
                {
                    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        if (httpResponse != null)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), ASCIIEncoding.UTF8))
                            {
                                if (htmlInnerText.Contains("barcode"))
                                {
                                    htmlInnerText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    if (htmlInnerText.Contains(">Tükendi</button>"))
                                    {
                                        tApiResult = "Tükendi";
                                        return await Task.FromResult(false);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        httpResponse.Close();
                                        reader.Close();
                                        return await Task.FromResult(true);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return await Task.FromResult(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tApiResult = "404 Page"; return await Task.FromResult(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    tApiResult = "404 Page";
                    Debug.WriteLine("GetUrlHtmlText => (" + barcode + "| Link : " + uri + " ) " + ex.ToString());
                    if (/*!ex.ToString().Contains("402") || !ex.ToString().Contains("502") ||*/ !ex.ToString().Contains("404"))
                    {
                        tApiResult = proxy;
                    }
                    return await Task.FromResult(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tApiResult = "404 Page";
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                db.InsertRekabetWinServError(OBJ_CompetitionItem.ID, "GetUrlHtmlText ==> " + ex.ToString());
                //MultiFuncComp.Manager.RekabetBrandManager.mobileNotification.SendNotification("<=A little Exception=>" + barcode, "ex str :>>  " + ex.ToString());
                tApiResult = proxy;
                return await Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
```

I have almost 400mbps downstream and upstream speed

[image: Computer features]

### EDIT:

This question was titled *How can I scrape 20.000 url same time in c#* and was closed for reason : "Opinion-based - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well."

I'm changing my question because I know how, but I am looking for advice specifically on how to improve the speed of this process.

Comment: Maybe this would be better off asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: THere are a lot of things that cause delays. Using raw threads to make IO calls. Using WebRequest. Faked "async" calls when all the code is synchronous

Comment: You can try to query a few dozen URLs at the same time, but if you try to query thousands, then your internet connection will become congested. More parallelism does not always mean more speed.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you so much for your answer, Could you have a chance to give some detail so that I can fully understand?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Do you have any suggestions so that I can progress without clogging? Can a bigger bandwidth solve my problem then?

Comment: With `HttpClient`+`async/await`+.NET Core 3.1 or newer you can at least double the throughput. Also your'e killing TLS security, that's not good.

Comment: A tip: you can remove `async` and all `await`s in `GetUrlHtmlText()` fluenly just `private Task<bool> GetUrlHtmlText()` and `return Task.FromResult(...)`. The method is synchronous but spend PS resources no `async` state machine. Finally you can just return `bool` without wrapping it with `Task`.

Comment: linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206351/12888024

Comment: @uayazzz what is the *actual* logic? Are you simply trying to find a page with the string `">Tükendi</button>"` ? Or do you want to do something with the pages?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hello,
I'm doing a scan on the html page for the "correct" return value. The return value of "exhausted" is "false". I do not take any action for these. So, I'm trying to weed out pages that don't say "barcode" and "> Out <".

Comment: @aepot I will try it , if I can get positive result I will be write there.